# third party api parsing, xml parsing, raw data parsing, ror parsing, ror nokoigiri, third party api parsing with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have an application in ruby on rails and have a raw format data file as a response from third party API. I want to parse that file in xml and get some element values as I am using nokogiri gem. So is there any way to parse that file?

here is detail of nokogiri

```
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use the title of the question as a repository of tags. Provide a short, descriptive sentence. I'd highly recommend reading "[ask]" along with the pages linked. Your question is premature and doesn't show any effort so “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?] (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” will be useful. Prior to asking you should have used Nokogiri's tutorial, searched the internet and Stack Overflow, then asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you already have installed Nokogiri, you need to pass the raw file to Nokogiri  to get the parsed response:

```
  parsed = Nokogiri::XML(raw_data)
  parsed = parsed.css("your_element_name").text
```